# Regex Match That doesn't contain some text

Tags: regex

I am tring to create a regex that finds a Start Prefix and an End Prefix that have paragraph tags between them. But the one i have cteated is not working to my expectations.

`%%%HL_START%%%(.*?)</p><p>(.*?)%%%HL_END%%%`

Correctly Matches
`<p>This Should %%%HL_START%%%Work</p><p>This%%%HL_END%%% SHould Match</p>`

This also matches but i dont want it to match becasue the `</p><p>` is not in bettween the Start and End Prefix

`<p>%%%HL_START%%%One%%%HL_END%%% Some More Text %%%HL_START%%%Here%%%HL_END%%%</p><p>Some more text %%%HL_START%%%Here%%%HL_END%%%</p>`

Comment: Your second example works because you can eat up enough content between the first `%%%HL_START%%%` and the last `%%%HL_END%%%` to match.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely comfortable that regex is the right solution here; if you are getting into nested start and stop markers, you might not have a regular language...

For this specific example, try changing the regex to use `[^%]` instead of `.` so that the `.*?`matching can't go past the `%%%%H:_END%%%%`

```
%%%HL_START%%%([^%]*?)</p><p>([^%]*?)%%%HL_END%%%
```